# ExpandableListView additional text in header

Tags: android

I want to create ExpandableTextView where in the right corner of the header will be a text or button. I've tried to find a solution, but I found only one way - replace groupIndicator with drawable and make a text inside a drawable. But is there a other way? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5GRb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with ExpandableListView you need an adapter:

1. Create a class ExpandableListViewAdapter which inherits from [BaseExpandableListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter)

   public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
2. Hand over an context in ExpandableListViewAdapter's constructor and save it as a member variable
3. Override method getGroupView(...)
4. Create a Relative Layout (android:orientation="horizontal") and include your TextViews etc. which you want to show in your ExpandableTextView and save it as group_view.xml
5. Inside getGroupView(.., View convertView, ...) inflate your view:

   LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext);

   convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);

   TextView yourTextView = convertView.findViewbyId(R.id.yourTextViewId);

Obviously you can customize your Layout, Views etc.
If you want to add individual data to each row you need to pass an Array in your constructor. Then you use the given parameter groupPosition in getGroupView() to access your data in your array.